# Array: "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, windows-server-2008

I get the following error on my web application: **"Index was outside the bounds of the array."**

The strange thing is, that the problem only comes on my webserver (Windows Server 2008 R2, .Net 4.0, Windows 7 Enterprise 64 Bit).

When I debug the site in Visual Studio, it all works perfect

The Code looks like this:

I define an array and give it to the class "CheckUserRights"

```
string NTLogin = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1].ToUpper();
string[] allowedRoles = new string[2] { "Administrator", "Superuser" };
CheckUserRights Check = new CheckUserRights(NTLogin, allowedRoles);
```

The class looks like this:

```
//Lokale Variablen definieren
string strUserName;
string strRolename;
string[] AllowedRoles;
bool boolAuthorized;

//Im Konstruktor definierte Werte übergeben.
public CheckUserRights(string Username, string[] Roles)
{
    this.strUserName = Username;
    this.AllowedRoles = Roles;
    getRoleForUser();
    checkRights();
}
...
...
```

I have searched for a solution after 4 hours, but I can't find anything. I am not a pro and that's the first time I have used arrays.

Could it be a wrong configuration on the server?

I am grateful for every help. Thanks!

**Update**

Solved, there was an problem in the server configuration. Solution is in the answer from Steve.

Comment: Can you show exact stack trace?

Comment: Any chance of the stacktrace?

Comment: Where are you getting the error? I can't see any access attempts to the array in your code...

Comment: i like that the comments are in german yet the function names are english :)

Comment: can you show us the code for the other two methods?

Comment: A stack trace would be useful.  The error could be in getRoleForUser or checkRights.  You need to show us the code.

Comment: Standard practise to use English for the code, especially since all of the .net framework is in English.

Comment: I can't see where iam getting the error, because i get the error only on the server. in visual studio it works, there is no error.

Comment: I guess the exception was thrown in `getRoleForUser()` :P

Comment: what is the stack trace? sry, i never heard that.

Comment: are you using the same database/storage for both the server and local host?

Comment: How about you show us the code for `getRoleForUser()` and `checkRights()`? discussing in comments won't help.

Comment: @user1221100 the stack trace is the bit under the picture youve linked us to

Comment: We really need to see the code for the other methods.  I am guessing that maybe one of your methods is returning no data, so when you try look at it the array is empty. Or as suggested by Jorge below you are forgetting indexes start at 0 and attempting to access an index that never existed.

Comment: @Purplegoldfish
I have post the complete code in my first answer. What I don't understand is, why do it works local when i debugg the site, but on the server i get an error. There are no problems with the array when I debugg, thats the strange :S

Comment: @user1221100 Maybe the webserver isnt returning data, so rdrR["RoleName"] may be throwing your exception.  I would add some try catch blocks to catch the exception. At least that way you can start to track down where it is happening

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many problems in that code, but, sticking to the problem on the question title I think that this line looks suspicious:

```
string NTLogin = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' })[1].ToUpper();
```

what happen if the Page.User.Identity.Name doesn't contain a DOMAIN\USERNAME?

Could be rewritten as

```
string[] nameparts = Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\\' });
string NTLogin = (nameparts.Length == 2 ? nameparts[1] : nameparts[0]).ToUpper();
if(NTLogin.Length == 0)
    return;
```

Why this property could be the error? [Look at this article](http://forums.asp.net/t/1272477.aspx)

Comment: Its an intranet-application. Every employee should has this information when he is on the net. But I will check this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your help. I have now try a few things and it could really probably be the problem from your linked site. All the "symtoms" are matching.

Comment: Now it works! Thank you very much. The problem was, that I had do disable "anonymous authentification" and enable "Windows authentification". Not the value from the "NTLogin"-Arry has a value and it works :D

Comment: @user1221100 Glad to be of help.  However, if I understand well, with "anonymous authentication" active then the Page.User.Identity.Name will be blank leading to the "Index was outside the bounds" error. Well, the problem has been resolved! Please accept the answer if you find it usefull.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your code is vulnerable to a SQL injection attack on the first select in getRoleForUser.  You should use a SqlParameter.

2) without a stack trace it makes it difficult to determine where the error is.  However, I think it maybe that the sql selects could return NO ROWS.  So, whenever you do a `r.Read`, change it to `if (!r.Read()) return;`.

Again, if you post the stack trace we can be of better help.

Answer (score 0):

How i solved was as follows:

```
Dim strname() As String
For indx = 0 To (strname.Length - 1)
    If strname(indx) = "" Then
    Else
        ListBox1.Items.Add(strname(indx))
    End If
Next
```